# Losing javascript functionality due to Bootstrap Tabs incompatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visual-studio-2015, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working from VS2015, JQuery 2.2.4 and Bootstrap 3.3.7, having issues with Bootstrap tabs component, since my dropdowns menu are not being displaying when I click over them. I have 5 tabs in total, with some tabs the dropdown objects at header & footer works properly but if click on other tabs then they stop working

```
 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<environment names="Development">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/header.css" />
    <link href="~/css/Video.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.0/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>        
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/images/favicon_azul-gris32px.png" />
</environment>
```

```
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-treeview/src/js/bootstrap-treeview.js"></script>
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.0/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.8.0/videojs-contrib-hls.min.js"></script>      
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
```

DROPDOWN:

```
<li class="dropdown">
                                    <a id="username_dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        @UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.Name
                                        <span class="caret"></span>

                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-account">
                                        <li id="menu-li-group">
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Groups" asp-action="Index">
                                                <img id="img-li-group" class="menu-icons-account" src="~/images/home-usermenu/UM_groups_inactive.png" />
                                                @Localizer["Groups"]
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="menu-li-users">
                                            <a asp-controller="ApplicationUsers" asp-action="Index">
                                                <img id="img-li-users" class="menu-icons-account" src="~/images/home-usermenu/UM_users_inactive.png" />
                                                @Localizer["Users"]
                                            </a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li id="menu-li-log">
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="LogAdminTasks" asp-action="Index">
                                                <img id="img-li-log" class="menu-icons-account" src="~/images/home-usermenu/UM_log_inactive.png" />
                                                @Localizer["Activity Log"]
                                            </a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li id="menu-li-profile">
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="ChangePassword">
                                                <img id="img-li-profile" class="menu-icons-account" src="~/images/home-usermenu/UM_edit_inactive.png" />
                                                @Localizer["Modify Profile"]
                                            </a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li id="menu-li-openapp">
                                            <a id="openNac" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                                <img id="img-li-openapp" class="menu-icons-account" src="~/images/home-usermenu/UM_sharimg_inactive.png" />
                                                @Localizer["Open Sharimg"]
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="menu-li-logoff">
                                            <a style="cursor: pointer;">
                                                <img id="img-li-logoff" class="menu-icons-account" src="~/images/home-usermenu/UM_logout_inactive.png" />

                                                <button id="btn_submit" type="submit" style="color:black" class="btn btn-link pull-right">@Localizer["Log off"]</button>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
```

Before I also loosed javascript functionality for Bootstrap tooltip and mouse over icons

[image: http://imgur.com/a/WHvv2]

Comment: please, paste relevant information only. BTW, Bootstrap 3.3.7 perfectly pairs with jQuery, infact, it has been built on top of it...

Comment: What kind of code you want me to share?  I have read that Bootstrap had have some kind of incompatibility with JQuery 3. I can add here that I had to put the jquery code inside the partial views (MVC) which are at the same time inside the tabs in order to get it working

Comment: you should avoid pasting not relevant code, this doesn't help to understand the problem. You should attach `stack trace` or provide a reproducible example rather than pasting pieces of DOM that don't say anything about your error.

[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -2):

there was no kind of incompatibility between my version of Bootstrap and Jquery.

I had 2 issues:

1- I was loading all the js libraries before closing the `<body>` tag in the main layout .cshtml file, so I cannot execute Jquery code in partials views, I just changed location after the `<header>` where I load all the .js files

2 - Due to this error I tried to load again all JS files in the partial view, despite this doesnt show any error in the console it stops some functionality as the Bootstrap Dropdown menu did

Comment: move this to the question area